# Access second, third, ... drawer of a window via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, drawer

I want to measure the size and position of a window including its drawers. I already found out how to get the size / position of the *first* drawer, but I can't find a way (neither Google neither trying) to access other drawers. You can access the first drawer doing something like the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set appProcess to the first process whose name is "DrawerTest"
  set appWindow to the first window of appProcess
  if (count drawers of appWindow) > 0 then
    set {{w, h}} to size of drawer of appWindow
    set {{x, y}} to position of drawer of appWindow
    set drawerBounds to {x, y, x + w, y + h}
  end if
end tell

drawerBounds
```

If I write `first drawer` or `drawer 1` I get the error `Execution Error: Can’t get item 1 of 116.` (last number varies) and `Error -1728.` (seems to vary sometimes, had `-1719` as well). If I cannot write `first` or `1` I can't write `second` or `2` (yield the same error). However, I'm sure there is a way since I can access the first drawer. Any ideas?

PS: For testing purposes I created a simple App which only contains a window with 4 buttons to trigger a drawer per edge. [I pushed it to github](https://github.com/florianpilz/DrawerTest), therefore you can clone it and play around by yourself if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple properties for a drawer, when you get the size of the drawer you are getting a list of the specified properties of the drawers (e.g. {{465, 117}} for one drawer). You can get an individual size by getting an item of that list (e.g. the first size, which is also a list, would be {465, 117}), but you could also just go through the current drawers, whatever they are.

```
repeat with aDrawer in (drawers of appWindow)
    set {w, h} to size of aDrawer
    set {x, y} to position of aDrawer
    -- add to overall window size if larger, etc
end repeat
```

Comment: Sorry I had no time to test and verify the solution until now. Works great and is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your explanation as well, copied the code from somewhere and tested it on an App with only one drawer and didn't see the point in the double nested list. :) Now everything is clear to me and I'm eager to use that knowledge. Thanks a lot!